# Как задать абстрактный метод с универсальной ссылкой?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, интерфейс, c++14

Есть класс Foo который принимает std::function по универсальной ссылке и делает передачу своему полю (на второй параметр метода Subscribe не обращайте внимания, это трейтсы проверяющие сигнатуру std::function.)

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Foo {
public:
    template <class T>
    void Subscribe(T&& in_val, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type, std::function<int(int)> >::value>::type* = 0) {
        OwnFunctor = std::forward<T>(in_val);
    };
    int Callback(int val) {
        return OwnFunctor(val);
    }
private:
    std::function<int(int)> OwnFunctor;
};

int Bat(int val){
    return val * val;
}

void main() {
    Foo foo;
    std::function<int(int)> Functor = Bat;
    foo.Subscribe(Functor); // Попытка передать lval
    cout << foo.Callback(5) << endl;;
    foo.Subscribe(std::move(Functor));// Попытка передать rval
    cout << foo.Callback(5) << endl;;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Этот код работает, но мне понадобилось создать две разных реализации Foo под разные платформы и пользоваться Foo через интерфейс BaseFoo. Т.е. этот код превращается в следующий:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits> 

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class BaseFoo {
public:
    template<class T>
    virtual void Subscribe(T&& in_val, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type, std::function<int(int)> >::value>::type* = 0) = 0;
    virtual int Callback(int val) = 0;
};

class Foo:public BaseFoo {
public:
    template <class T>
    void Subscribe(T&& in_val, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type, std::function<int(int)> >::value>::type* = 0) override {
        OwnFunctor = std::forward<T>(in_val);
    };
    int Callback(int val) override {
        return OwnFunctor(val);
    }
private:
    std::function<int(int)> OwnFunctor;
};

int Bat(int val){
    return val * val;
}

void main() {
    Foo foo;
    BaseFoo* base_foo= &foo;
    std::function<int(int)> Functor = Bat;
    base_foo->Subscribe(Functor); // Попытка передать lval
    cout << foo.Callback(5) << endl;;
    base_foo->Subscribe(std::move(Functor));// Попытка передать rval
    cout << foo.Callback(5) << endl;;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

И тут собственно и возникает проблема. Метод Subscribe должен быть абстрактным, но что бы in_val была универсальной ссылкой он должен быть еще и шаблонным. Как мне создать абстрактный метод с универсальной ссылкой?

Comment: Зачем тут шаблон, если принимаются только объекты `std::function<int(int)>`? Шаблон ради универсальной ссылки тут лишний (так как больше никакого обобщенного кода нет), проще сделать две пергрузки.

Comment: @VTT что бы была возможность копировать, когда необходимо копировать и перемещать, когда мне необходимо перемещение. Пример как вы понимаете надуманный =) но смысл вопроса от этого не меняется. Если вам будет удобней можете заменить std::function на std::vector.

Comment: Я к тому, что у вас есть возможность копировать, когда необходимо копировать, и перемещать, когда необходимо перемещать и без использования этого шаблона... У вас есть шаблон, но *в таком виде* он не дает преимуществ по сравнению с перегрузкой. Скорее даже наоборот, так как перегрузка вроде выходит покороче.

Comment: @VTT перегрузка заставит держать две версии одного и того же метода с практическим идентичным кодом (которого может стать очень много со временем), что очень плохо для сопровождения и безопасности. Если не применять универсальные ссылки и std::forward а таких ситуация то зачем они тогда вообще нужны?

Comment: Вообще-то в таком виде как раз шаблонный код у вас получается сложнее и соответственно хуже для сопровождения и безопасности чем две перегрузки. Две перегрузки вполне уместны как и например существование конструктора копирования и конструктора перемещения. Тем более они могут быть виртуальными. От универсальных ссылок толк мог бы быть, если бы код был более обобщенным.

Comment: @VTT про этот конкретный пример я и не спорю. Я же говорю, что он надуманный. Если уж на то пошло то перемещение std::functional тут вообще смысла не имеет, проще её всегда копировать, работать будет так-же быстро. Я учу С++ и сейчас я встал перед вопросом "Как задать абстрактный метод с универсальной ссылкой?". Код, который я написал, это просто мой пример, в который я решил это встроить. Я же говорю что вы в уме можете заменить std::functional на std::vector и поместить в метод 1000 строк кода со множествами std::forward<T> и прочим. Суть вопроса от этого не измениться.

Comment: Универсальные ссылки не могут использоваться в виртуальных методах, так как виртуальные методы не могут быть шаблонами. Как вариант: можно вызывать виртуальный метод из шаблонного метода  с универсальной ссылкой.

Comment: @VTT т.е. стандарт языка вообще не подразумевает создание интерфейсов с применением универсальных ссылок в своей сигнатуре? Очень жаль на самом деле((. Спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: не думаю, что это невозможно. Лично я подумаю над этим, так что отметил вопрос как полезный(только  не нужно сделать виртуальный метод шаблонным, нужно искать другой подход )

Comment: Это ограничение связано с необходимостью хранить указатели на функцию в таблице виртуальных функций. Для нешаблонной функции в таблице придется хранить один указатель. В случае шаблонной функции пришлось бы хранить неопределённое количество указателей - по одному для каждого варианта.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan спасибо большое.

Comment: @VTT Вы писали "Как вариант: можно вызывать виртуальный метод из шаблонного метода с универсальной ссылкой". Как это сделать? У меня же указатель интерфейса, а не реализации.

Comment: Но виртуальный метод-то вызвать все равно можно.

Comment: @VTT Как это сделать это в смысле как вызвать шаблонны метод, из которого вы предлагаете вызывать виртуальный?

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что шаблонный метод реализуется в базовом абстрактном классе.

Comment: @VTT Всё. Теперь понял. Но так не чего не решается т.е. на передаче в виртуальный метод универсальность ссылки сохранить не получится. И мы опять приходим либо к необходимости перегрузки, либо к принудительному копированию объекта. Т.е. всё тоже самое + оверхэд.

Comment: Почему не решается? Виртуальный метод может принимать rvalue reference, а копирование при наличии возможности будет выполнятся с перемещением, т.е. универсальная ссылка будет работать.

Comment: @VTT но std::forward внутри реализации метода работать как надо не будет (собственно ради чего всё и затевалось). Если так рассуждать, то rvalue reference можно было использовать с самого начала (в самом первом примере) и не париться со всеми этими шаблонами. Но это не была бы работа с универсальными ссылками.

Answer (score 2):

Назначение универсальной ссылки в том, чтобы вместо создания объекта из аргументов в месте вызова функции и последующего копирования в место использования передать аргументы конструктора по ссылке и конструировать объект непосредственно на месте использования.

Если вы знаете, что аргументом функции является `std::functional<T>`, значит вы просто можете принимать объект `std::functional<T>` по значению - тогда он будет один раз скопирован, когда аргумент `const std::functional<T>`, или один раз перемещен в остальных случаях. В C++17 еще добавилась эллизия копирования.

Попробую привести пример, когда универсальная ссылка полезна:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class S>
constexpr bool is_functional_onject_v  = std::is_constructible_v<std::function<S>, T> 
                                         && !std::is_same_v<T, std::nullptr_t>;

class Foo{
public:
    // В место T может быть набор аргументов, но тогда нужен другой механизм sfinae
    template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<is_functional_onject_v<std::decay_t<T>, int(int)>>>
    int call(T&& fn){
       std::cout << "вызов Foo::call\n"; // Любое дополнительное действие
       return on_call(std::forward<T>(fn));
    }

    virtual ~Foo(){}
private:
    virtual int on_call(std::function<int(int)> fn) = 0;
};

class Impl: public Foo{
    int m_value;
public:
    Impl(int value): m_value(value)
    { }

    ~Impl() override{}

private:
    int on_call(std::function<int(int)> fn){
        return fn(m_value);
    }
};

struct TestFn{
   TestFn() = default;
   TestFn(const TestFn&){
       std::cout << "Копирование TestFn\n";
   }
   TestFn(TestFn&&){
       std::cout << "Перемещение TestFn\n";
   }

   int operator()(int v){return v - 15;}
};

int bar(){
    Impl impl(42);
    Foo& foo = impl;

    TestFn fn;
    return foo.call(std::move(fn));

}
```

При этом произойдет два перемещения `TestFn`: одно при передечt в конструктор `std::function`, одно при перемещении самой `std::function`. Если бы аргументом функции `call` был непосредственно `std::function` - перемещений було бы уже три.

Можно сократить количество перемещений до одного, если, как советовали в комментариях, создать две виртуальные функции - одна принимает `const std::function&`, другая - `std::function&&`. Но тогда каждая реализация должна реализовывать обе эти функции. Компромиссный вариант - обязать ревлизовывать только перегрузку с передачей по `rvalue`, а для `lvalue` реализация по умолчанию перемешает аргумент в реализацию с `rvalue`. Тогда при вызове `call` с `lvalue` будет одно копирование и одно перемещение, с `rvalue`  - одно перемещение, и потомки могут оптимизировать вариант с копированиемпри необходимости.